# Kendo-grid not paging local data

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to make paging work with local data. Currently I have a DataSource:

```
vm.kendoData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverPaging: true,
        pageSize: 5
    });
```

And when I get the data from server it is assigned to the DS:

```
vm.kendoData.data = $scope.records;
```

The following is the grid mark-up:

```
<kendo-grid data-source="vm.kendoData.data" options="vm.gridOptions"><kendo-grid>
```

And this is the options definition:

```
vm.gridOptions = {
        columns: [
            {
                field: "Col1",
                title: "Col1",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "Col2",
                title: "Col2",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "Col3",
                title: "Col3",
                width: "120px"
            }, {
                field: "Col4",
                title: "Col4",
                width: "120px"
            }
        ],
        pageSize: 10,
        pageable: true,
        dataBound: function () {
            this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add data example if you have

Comment: If you already fetch data from the server, why don't you create a remote datasource with paging on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's why it doesn't work as you expect:

1. Since your datasource is local, `serverPaging` should be set to false (because there's no call to a server)
2. `pageSize` is not an option of `grid`, it's an option of `grid.pageable`, [but the documentation states](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/pageable):

> Don't forget to set a `pageSize`, no matter if paging is performed client-side or server-side. A `pageSize` can be defined in the `pageable` settings, or in the `dataSource` settings. **If an already existing `datasource` instance is passed to the grid, then the `pagesize` option should be set in the dataSource's settings and not in the `pageable` settings**.

So to sum up:

```js
vm.kendoData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: false,
    pageSize: 5, 
    data: $scope.records
});

vm.gridOptions = {
    columns: [
        {
            field: "Col1",
            title: "Col1",
            width: "120px"
        }, {
            field: "Col2",
            title: "Col2",
            width: "120px"
        }, {
            field: "Col3",
            title: "Col3",
            width: "120px"
        }, {
            field: "Col4",
            title: "Col4",
            width: "120px"
        }
    ],
    pageable: true,
    dataBound: function () {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
}
```

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/86w9u27h/7/

Note: since you're already fetching data from the server, why don't you create a remote datasource with paging on the server?

Comment: I am marking this as accepted asnwer 'cause this pointed me out in the right direction, thanks for this explanation!
What I had to do was to initialize the datasource inside the function that get data, my fail.